# Django Custom User Model and SuperUser

Tags: django, django-models, django-authentication, django-users, django-auth-models

I am trying to create an app which a web3 user can use their wallet to sign in **BUT I want the superuser to still use a username/password.** (my future plan is to create a custom backend to do the web3 auth flow)

I was close with this as I was able to create a first admin that could use the username/password but realized it was failing on the next  createsuperuser with this:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: users_web3user.public_address
```

So I tried for now just adding a random integer to satisfy that just to see if it would work but the same issue constantly shows up.

Would this be the proper way to go about this and to seperate my users from my superusers?
Also, my debugger is never called even though I have set in my settings.py where `user` is my app:
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.Web3User'

models.py:
class Web3UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, public_address):
if not public_address:
raise ValueError('Users must have a public_address')

```
        user = self.model(
            public_address=public_address,
            nonce=secrets.token_urlsafe(32)
        )

        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, password=None):
        import ipdb; ipdb.sset_trace()
        public_address=secrets.randbelow(299)
        print(public_address)
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            password=password,
            public_address=public_address
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user



class Web3User(AbstractUser):
    public_address = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True)
    nonce = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

Comment: Did you realise that your debugger is never hit? Set `objects = Web3UserManager()` in `Web3User` and you should be able to figure out the rest.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because while similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.

Comment: sure!  I figured it out too btw!

Answer (score -1):

```
django_custom_user==0.7
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'user.UserModel' -> settings.py

class UserModel(AbstractEmailUser, BaseModelFields):
   pass
```

Use package instead of making some cool logic.

Comment: I am not trying to implement emails in users. 
I need two diff user models for superuser and a regular user.